# Process two dimensional list (string)?

Tags: array

i have a two dimensional array/list populated but need help on how to iterate thru it:

```
List< List<string>> Wdays = new List< list<string>>();
List< String> Mnth = new List< String>();    

Mnth.add('JAN'); Mnth.add(string.valueof(jan));
Wdays.add(mnth);

Mnth.add('FEB'); Mnth.add(string.valueof(feb));
Wdays.add(mnth);
```

I wish to know how to loop thru the two dimensional list to display the values...any help please?

Comment: Why is `Mnth` holding values of both months and days of the week?  Your variable names are making this harder than it has to be

Comment: Sorry crop, while copying from the console i referred a different line...corrected now for understanding

Comment: Yes but what is `WDays`? Presumably you need  a list of months that in turn is a list of weeks ?  [Jan] [W1], [Jan] [W2], ... [Feb] [W1], ...[Dec][W5] or something like this. Or, if this is a full calendar, you need a list of months that is a list of weeks that is a list of days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use two `for` loops

```
For(List< String> inner : wdays){
    for(String day : inner){
           System.debug(day);
     }
}
```